# Sympy: Solve bi-variate inequalities

Tags: python, math, sympy, equation, inequality

I would like to know if it is possible to solve a specific case of system of inequalities using Sympy.

Each system will contain one bi-variate inequality plus additional optional uni-variate inequalities  containing the same variables as the first inequality.

Example:

```
a*b <= 100
a > 0
```

I would like to get symbolic solutions for each variable as Piecewise function.

Solutions for the previous example would be:

Solution for A:

```
a > 0, when b <= 0
a in (0, 100/b], when b > 0.
```

Solution for B:

```
b <= 100/a, when a > 0.
```

Microsoft Math Solver can correctly solve these types of inequalities so it can be used as a reference:
https://mathsolver.microsoft.com/en/solve-problem/%7B%20a%20%20%7D%5E%7B%20%20%20%7D%20%20b%20%3C%20%20%20%3D%20%20100%20%2C%20%20a%20%3E%20%200